# MapBox Studio GeoTif appear black?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

when loading a GeoTIFF file into MapBox Studio it appears black with extended boundaries as shown below the file represent FAA sectional chart 
 
. [image] .

From searching online all the references point out that pixels with no data appear black in jpg file that doesn't support transparency

I tried several approaches as follow none of them worked to fix the issue;

```
 1. (https://www.mapbox.com/help/troubleshoot-raster-transparency-issues/)
     The first command failed with Index out of bound  

 2. gdal_translate -of GTiff -co PROFILE=GeoTIFF in.tiff out.tiff

 3. gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 input.tif output.tif

 4. gdalbuildvrt -of GTIFF -srcnodata 0 input.tif myVrt.vrt 
    gdal_translate -of GTIFF -scale -a_nodata 0 myVrt.vrt output.tif
```

Also I followed the tutorial (http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) & ((https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-tiff/)) applied the above with no success . 

 Is there a way to fix this issue or I'm just missing something using Mapbox Studio ?

Thanks in Advance
 
Mo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after trying I give up on loading GeoTiff directly to MapBox. Using the following commands to create a MBTiles from the GeoTIFF then loaded into MapBox Studio. I also used QGIS for clipping GeoTiFF

GDAL commands to convert GeoTIFF image to MBTiles. Requires GDAL 2.1+

```
 gdal_translate -expand rgb -of GTIFF f.tif f_1.tif
 gdal_translate f_1.tif image.mbtiles -of MBTILES
 gdaladdo image.mbtiles 2 4 8
```

Hope that would help others

Comment: Mine,  This tileset isn't visible from your map view!

Do you have any experiences with kind of this?